# Google Apps for Mail - MX entry related doubt

Tags: vps, domain-name, g-suite, mx-record

I have signed up for google apps recently for my organisation. The google apps guide says that I need to edit the MX entry for my domain so that the mails get redirected to the google mail servers instead of my default mail server. But, I am having a doubt whether to edit the MX entry on my domain name provider or the hosting server. My domain name provider is godaddy.com and my server is ServInt. And, moreover, what difference does it make if I edit the MX entries on my hosting provider or my domain name provider.

Thanks,
niting

P.S.The nameservers for the site are hosted on ServInt and am not using GoDaddy's nameserver services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to make these changes on your DNS settings for your domain name.  Not the host for your website.  I am assuming you use GoDaddy for this purpose and Servlnt to host your website.  To be sure, look at the name servers when performing a whois lookup for your domain.  That will tell you where your DNS settings are hosted.

Comment: The nameservers for the site are hosted on ServInt and am not using GoDaddy's nameserver services.

Comment: Then you will want to make the change on ServInt.

Answer (score 1):

MX records are a specific type of DNS record, thus whoever hosts your DNS records will make the change.